# How to set h2.jdbc from application.properties file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, h2

I am a fan of H2, and H2-Console. Unfortunatly, when i run the h2 on my java spring-boot application, by default the `JDBC URL` is as `jdbc:h2:~/test`
meanwhile it should be `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` to be able to see the saved objects.

So, **I am wondering if there is a way to configure this JDBC URL from the** `application.properties` or not?

The below image shows better what i am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below properties for connecting `h2` database via `application.properties` file

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb 
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```