# How to specify for H2 console JDBC URL using In-Memory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, h2

I'm following [Spring in Action book](https://livebook.manning.com/book/spring-in-action-fifth-edition/chapter-3/) and trying to get correct login page using H2 console. 
If I write `localhost:8080/h2-console`, I'm getting always like:
[image]

instead of it:

[image]

I've added *application.properties* file inside src/main/resources folder as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46503850/8370915), [here](https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-h2-in-memory-database) and [here](http://progressivecoder.com/setting-up-h2-database-with-spring-boot/) with these lines:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

but the result is the same and URL is again - `jdbc:h2:~/test`.

POM file is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sia</groupId>
    <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>taco-cloud</name>
    <description>Taco Cloud Example</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE
        </version> <!-- Sticking with 2.0.0.RELEASE for now. Problem with GeneratedKeyHolder in 2.0.1.RELEASE and higher. -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- H2 1.4.197 breaks auto-incrementing identity columns for some reason -->
        <h2.version>1.4.196</h2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tag::jdbcStarter[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::jdbcStarter[] -->
        <!-- tag::h2database[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::h2database[] -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Full code-example is from [here](https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-5-samples/tree/master/ch03).

Can it be because of incorrect versions of specific dependencies? Missing dependencies or something else? Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.